# How can I wire up a progress bar to my Speech Synthesizer?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, progress-bar, progress, speechsynthesizer

I would like to wire up a progress bar to my Speech Synthesizer within my application (to show how far through it is reading the text).

The the main components for my SpeechSynthesizer code are as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Start button
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            if (Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text != "")
            {
                reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                reader.SpeakAsync(Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text);
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                reader.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(reader_SpeakCompleted);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert text before launching Text to Speech.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Pause button
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                if (reader.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking)
                {
                    reader.Pause();
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                }
            }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Resume button
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                if (reader.State == SynthesizerState.Paused)
                {
                    reader.Resume();
                }
                button3.Enabled = false;
            }
            }


        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Stop button
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

I would like to wire this code up to a progress bar so that it displays the current status of the Speech Synthesizer (and pauses/stops when the user pauses/stops the progress bar. Is this possible? I've never used a progress bar properly, so I'd like some help on how to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: You can only show a "real" progress bar for things where you can actually detect the progress.  `reader.SpeakAsync()` is not one of those.  You can create a "fake" progress bar by estimating how long text of a given length will take to read and progressing based on that.  Those are far more common, as witnessed by installers which fill their bar over and over again...

Comment: The issue is that the text length varies, as it's a text editor.

Comment: You'd need something you could count to be returned as it's reading, which doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: So is it not possible to achieve this, then?

Comment: Well Bobson was saying you could estimate it.  You could get the number of words/characters/syllables from the text and guess how long it will take to run.

Comment: But as I said, the length of the text varies, as it's a text editor, so this is difficult to predict...

Comment: You're getting the text with  Basic_Word_Processor.Instance.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text, right? Why can't you count that?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, I misread his comment. How could I do this?

Comment: I'd create a timer.  Say you read in 200 words, and estimate each word is 1 second.  Create a timer that ticks every 2 seconds that increases your progress bar by 1%.  Or something similar.

Comment: Okay. I'll have a look into it.

Comment: What @Jonesy said.  You'll have to experiment to get a good "tick" length, and if there's a lot of words that it reads slowly (or quickly) you'll be off, but it should average out under most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the SpeakProgress event of your SpeechSynthesizer object.

```
reader.SpeakProgress += reader_SpeakProgress;
```

SpeakProgressEventArgs passes enough information to update a progress bar after each word is spoken.

```
private void reader_SpeakProgress(Object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar.Value = (Int32)((e.CharacterPosition + e.CharacterCount - 82F) / richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length * 100);
}
```

The "*- 82F*" offset is explained in the following excerpt from Microsoft's [SpeakProgressEventArgs.CharacterPosition Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speakprogresseventargs.characterposition(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> The CharacterPosition includes the count for characters in XML tags, including their enclosing brackets. When using any of the AppendText, AppendTextWithAlias, AppendTextWithHint, AppendSsmlMarkup, or AppendTextWithPronunciation methods, the contents are added to an SSML prompt that includes the opening and closing speak elements. The opening speak element adds an offset of 82 characters and spaces to the CharacterPosition of the all the words and letters in the prompt...